# Update a field declared as a val

Tags: scala

I saw this `class` definition in an online course that I'm taking:

```
   class Img(val width: Int, val height: Int, private val data: Array[Int]) {
      def this(w: Int, h: Int) = this(w, h, new Array(w * h))
      def apply(x: Int, y: Int): Int = data(y * width + x)
      def update(x: Int, y: Int, c: Int): Unit = data(y * width + x) = c
    }
```

I'm confused. How can we updated `data` like this `data(y * width + x) = c` even though it's declared as `val`?

Is this a more widely used pattern?

Comment: It's kinda like `final int[10] data` in Java. You can't change the reference, but you can it's content, if it is mutable, in this case it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`val` says you can't change *value* that is once assinged to `data`. This *value* is a reference to an array, so `data` will always point to the same array, but the array itself is mutable and you can always change its contents.